# can't commit and sync in github

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, github, synchronization

First step, create a new project called "X2" by Xcode, and clicked

> Source Control: Create git repository on My mac

Secondly, make a new git dir at another place for pushing by following command line

> cd ~/documents/Temp
>
> mkdir X2
>
> cd X2
>
> git init --bare .git

Thirdly, back to Xcode, add below under SourceControl > X2 > Configure X2 > Remote

> ~/documents/Temp/X2/.git

and then do some changes in the codes, then commit/push to X2/master(Create)

as of now, everything is ok, successfully.

Back to Github client, and **~/documents/Temp/X2** as a local repository, it already captured changes of push happened.

**BUT**, when click button of **Commit & Sync**, it said "no changes selected". click button "Edit" of push just happened, it shows:

> Could not edit commit
>
> Failed to reset repository to commit 1d42d81bc45dbec791f59a8c11ae719018c3469f.

Some screen shots for reference

Github client captured commit and push done in Xcode
[image: Github client captured commit and push done in Xcode]

The commit and push done in Xcode called **"in"**
[image: The commit and push done in Xcode called **in**]

click button **Commit & Sync**
[image: click button **Commit & Sync**]

click button **Edit**
[image: click button **Edit**]

So, my question is what happened on Github client? How to fix this problem?

Comment: The screenshot mention `~/Documents/GoogleDrive/X2`: did you add files there, before committing and pushing?

Comment: Yes. Commit and push in Xcode as mentioned above in the sentence before "as of now..."